# Can't make Context API work on React application, Uncaught TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...) is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-context

I'm trying to make ContextAPI work on my application, webpack compiles everything, but on the browser I get

> Uncaught TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)
> is not iterable

This is the first I'm trying to use ContextAPI in a project.

On index.js

```
 ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Router>
            <RoutesTree />
        </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

on RoutesTree.js

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
    state: {
        users: [],
        teams: []
    },
    setState: () => {}
};

export const AppContext = createContext(DEFAULT_STATE);

const RoutesTree = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(DEFAULT_STATE.state);
    const value = useMemo(
      () => ((state, setState)),
      [state]
    );
  
    console.log('state', state);

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={value}>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<App />} />
                <Route path='/teams/:id' element={<Team />} />
            </Routes>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default RoutesTree;
```

on App.js (work in progress)

```
const App = () => {

  return (
      <>
          <Home />
      </>
  );
}
```

on Home.js

```
const Home = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useContext(AppContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getTeams = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get(teamsApiUrl);
            
            setState((prevState) => ({
                teams: response.data,
                users: prevState.users
            }));
        }

        getTeams();
    }, [])
```

Complete error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...) is not iterable
    Home webpack://ecore-project/./src/components/Home/Home.js?:32
    React 16
    <anonymous> webpack://ecore-project/./src/index.js?:15
    js http://localhost:8080/main.js:500
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8080/main.js:1313
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/main.js:2403
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/main.js:2405 main.js line 434 > eval:32:78 The above error occurred in the <Home> component:

Home@webpack://ecore-project/./src/components/Home/Home.js?:32:78 App Routes@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/react-router/index.js?:922:7 RoutesTree@webpack://ecore-project/./src/components/RoutesTree/RoutesTree.js?:25:76 Router@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/react-router/index.js?:860:7 BrowserRouter@webpack://ecore-project/./node_modules/react-router-dom/index.js?:122:7

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries. react-dom.development.js:18572:15
    React 16
    <anonymous> webpack://ecore-project/./src/index.js?:15
    js http://localhost:8080/main.js:500
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8080/main.js:1313
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/main.js:2403
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/main.js:2405 Uncaught TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...) is not iterable
    Home webpack://ecore-project/./src/components/Home/Home.js?:32
    React 13
    <anonymous> webpack://ecore-project/./src/index.js?:15
    js http://localhost:8080/main.js:500
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8080/main.js:1313
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/main.js:2403
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/main.js:2405
```

webpack compiler:

```
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://192.168.0.100:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'C:\Users\Alvaro\git\ecore-project\public' directory
asset main.js 1.84 MiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset ./index.html 230 bytes [emitted]
runtime modules 27.5 KiB 14 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.61 MiB 90 modules
asset modules 4.4 KiB
  data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=%27.. 281 bytes [built] [code generated]
  data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=%27.. 279 bytes [built] [code generated]
  data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=%27.. 161 bytes [built] [code generated]
  data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=%27.. 271 bytes [built] [code generated]
  + 12 modules
modules by path ./src/ 12.8 KiB
  modules by path ./src/components/ 7.9 KiB 6 modules
  modules by path ./src/*.js 683 bytes 2 modules
  modules by path ./src/*.css 2.66 KiB 2 modules
  ./src/utils/usePagination.js 1.59 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.72.1 compiled successfully in 1741 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is how you are trying to compute a memoized context value.

```
const value = useMemo(
  () => ((state, setState)), // <-- not an iterable value!
  [state]
);
```

It's not exactly what you think it is, and the code blows up in the `Home` component when it tries to use array destructuring assignment to access the state and state updater function.

```
const [state, setState] = useContext(AppContext); // <-- tries to access array
```

`() => ((state, setState))` is actually returning the result of a [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) expression. The `setState` function is what is returned as a memoized value.

Compounding this issue is that the context value was declared to be an object and not an array.

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  state: {
    users: [],
    teams: []
  },
  setState: () => {}
};

export const AppContext = createContext(DEFAULT_STATE);
```

## Solution

I am certain you meant to memoize an object instead.

```
const value = useMemo(
  () => ({ state, setState }),
  [state]
);
```

Now the consumer needs to destructure the object correctly. It's an object, not an array.

```
const { state, setState } = useContext(AppContext);
```